# How to customize an existing Grails plugin functionality, modifying behavior of doWithSpring method

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, spring-ldap

I am new to grails and while working with Spring Security LDAP plugin it was identified that it accepts the ldap server password in plain text only. The task in hand is to pass an encrypted password which is decrypted before it is consumed by the plugin during its initialization phase.

I have already searched for all possible blogs and stackoverflow questions but could not find a way to extend the main plugin class to simply override the doWithSpring() method so that i can simply add the required decryption logic for the Ldap server password. Any help here will be appreciated.

I have already seen and tried jasypt plugin but it also does not work well if the password is stored in some external file and not application yml. So I am looking for a solution to extend the Spring security plugin main class, add the required behavior and register the custom class.

EDIT

Adding the snippet from Grails LDAP Security plugin, which I am trying to override. So If i am successfully able to update the value of securityConfig object before the plugin loads, the purpose is solved.

Some snippet from the plugin:

```
def conf = SpringSecurityUtils.securityConfig
...
...

contextSource(DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource, conf.ldap.context.server) { // 'ldap://localhost:389'
        authenticationSource = ref('ldapAuthenticationSource')
        authenticationStrategy = ref('authenticationStrategy')
        userDn = conf.ldap.context.managerDn // 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com'
        **password = conf.ldap.context.managerPassword // 'secret'**
        contextFactory = contextFactoryClass
        dirObjectFactory = dirObjectFactoryClass
        baseEnvironmentProperties = conf.ldap.context.baseEnvironmentProperties // none
        cacheEnvironmentProperties = conf.ldap.context.cacheEnvironmentProperties // true
        anonymousReadOnly = conf.ldap.context.anonymousReadOnly // false
        referral = conf.ldap.context.referral // null
    }

    ldapAuthenticationSource(SimpleAuthenticationSource) {
        principal = conf.ldap.context.managerDn // 'cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com'
        **credentials = conf.ldap.context.managerPassword // 'secret'**
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to override the `doWithSpring()` method in the existing plugin.  You can provide your own plugin which loads after the one you want to affect and have your `doWithSpring()` add whatever you want to the context.  If you add beans with the same name as the ones added by the other plugin, yours will replace the ones provided by the other plugin as long as you configure your plugin to load after the other one.  Similarly, you could do the same think in `resources.groovy` of the app if you don't want to write a plugin for this.

You have other options too.  You could write a bean post processor or bean definition post processor that affects the beans created by the other plugin.  Depending on the particulars, that might be a better idea.

**EDIT:**

After seeing your comment below I created a simple example that shows how you might use a definition post processor.  See the project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/postprocessordemo.

The interesting bits:

https://github.com/jeffbrown/postprocessordemo/blob/master/src/main/groovy/demo/SomeBean.groovy

```
package demo

class SomeBean {

    String someValue

}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/postprocessordemo/blob/master/src/main/groovy/demo/SomePostProcessor.groovy

```
package demo

import org.springframework.beans.BeansException
import org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues
import org.springframework.beans.PropertyValue
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.BeanDefinition
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistry
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor

class SomePostProcessor implements BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor{
    @Override
    void postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(BeanDefinitionRegistry registry) throws BeansException {
        BeanDefinition definition = registry.getBeanDefinition('someBean')
        MutablePropertyValues values = definition.getPropertyValues()
        PropertyValue value = values.getPropertyValue('someValue')
        def originalValue = value.getValue()

        // this is where you could do your decrypting...
        values.addPropertyValue('someValue', "MODIFIED: ${originalValue}".toString())
    }

    @Override
    void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/postprocessordemo/blob/master/grails-app/conf/spring/resources.groovy

```
beans = {
    someBean(demo.SomeBean) {
        someValue = 'Some Value'
    }

    somePostProcessor demo.SomePostProcessor
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/postprocessordemo/blob/master/grails-app/init/postprocessordemo/BootStrap.groovy

```
package postprocessordemo

import demo.SomeBean

class BootStrap {

    SomeBean someBean

    def init = { servletContext ->
        log.info "The Value: ${someBean.someValue}"
    }

    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

At application startup you will see log output that looks something like this...

```
2017-10-23 19:04:54.356  INFO --- [           main] postprocessordemo.BootStrap              : The Value: MODIFIED: Some Value
```

The "MODIFIED" there is evidence that the bean definition post processor modified the property value in the bean.  In my example I am simply prepending some text to the string.  In your implementation you could decrypt a password or do whatever you want to do there.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, trying for the post processor first. Will revert based on the results.

Comment: I tried that and was able to capture and modify the configObject class for the SpringSecurityUtils inside BeanPostProcessor but unfortunately it seems that GrailsPlugins are loaded and initialized before the BeanPostProcessor itself.
My modified value of the ldapPassword was not picked up.

Added the snippet from the grails plugin in my query above.

Comment: "I tried that and was able to capture and modify the configObject class for the SpringSecurityUtils inside BeanPostProcessor" - I wouldn't recommend doing that.  I would modify the bean definition.

Comment: Found another solution for this, during the initialization and loading of application yml file intercepted the loader and decoded the required property. Will add detailed solution in sometime as it may help others. 

Upvoting your solution as it helped me with another use case. Thanks for taking out time and your help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying Jasypt plugin and BeanPostProcessor solutions unsuccessfully for my use case, I found below solution to work perfectly.

To describe again the problem statement here, 
a) we had to keep the passwords in an encrypted format inside properties files
b) and given we were packaging as a war file so the properties must not be kept inside the war to allow automated deployment scripts update the encrypted passwords depending on the environment

Jasypt plugin was a perfect solution for the use case a), but it was not able to cover the b) scenario
Moreover, the Grails LDAP Security plugin was getting loaded quite early hence Bean Post processors were also not helping out here.

Solution: 
Created a new class by implementing the interface SpringApplicationRunListener. Extended its methods and parsed the properties file using YamlPropertySourceLoader

Sample code:

```
YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader(); 
  PropertySource<?> applicationYamlPropertySource = loader.load( 
    "application.yml", new ClassPathResource("application.yml"),"default"); 
  return applicationYamlPropertySource;
```

Once the properties were loaded inside the MapPropertySource object, parsed them for the encrypted values and applied the decryption logic.

This whole implementation was executed before any plugins were initialized during Grails bootup process solving the purpose.

Hope it will help others.